# Invalid session in Sencha Architect

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I've been trying to create a new Sencha ID, but it always shows the error message

[image]

They don't mention any thing over here, a simple message which doesn't show what kind of error we are doing there. Did anyone face this issue?

Any solution for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen due to the service change in the Sencha Forums.

An easy work around is to create your forum account via the forum here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/register.php

Comment: Still a workaround. Would you happen to know what the actual problem is?

Comment: The whole authentication system has been changed and Architect will be updated soon